# Can not type or past < and | symbols

Tags: keyboard

I am setting up my droplet in DigitalOcean. Through web interface I am connected to Ubuntu 18.04 terminal.

When I try to type symbols < or | they are displayed as >. When I past code from my system through web interface with these symbols, it just replaces them to >

What can be the reason and how to type them?

Comment: which operating system and language you normally use? the problem may be keyboard layout that may be different between your operating system and DO default keyboard layout

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and English.

Comment: Which keyboard layout in Ubuntu has these characters?

Comment: is your keyboard having this layout?
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0810/3669/files/mac-us-international-keyboard_1024x1024.png?7339475165509707763

Comment: Yes, but in console these keys just type >

Comment: The problem is, even when I paste the code it changes these characters

Comment: In that case I believe you should contact DO support. This is not default ubuntu behaviour. However, this can also be fault of the SSH client you're using (the web one), so please make sure you use some good ssh client (one called "putty" should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

As DigitalOcean support says: 
"Our engineers are aware of the issue affecting proper keystroke entry in the web console, and they are working on overhauling the experience. In the meantime, we recommend that you access your Droplet via SSH."